# How can I create inexpensive storage?

Tags: kitchens, furniture, storage, recycling

Do you know of any origami techniques or related cheap alternatives to save or store things like socks, kitchen stuff or other small objects without having to buy heavy and expensive furniture?

Comment: http://www.google.com/images?q=fedex+furniture

Comment: @Lev -- I had the same thought when I first saw this question.  Just don't go posting pictures of things you make online, as [FedEx doesn't like that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FedEx_furniture)

Comment: Wow, awesome! I didn't know about that Fedex furniture stuff. Awesome, indeed.

Comment: This question is a bit of a non-sequitur. Socks can be stored in pretty much anything, and I'm not sure what origami has to do with it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in paper? ... hope not :)

but there are websites that can be helpful in reusing stuff we already have / receive from others

> http://www.ikeahackers.net/

is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

[Bloxes](http://bloxes.com/) can be made into shelving, furniture, decorative items, etc.

The only downside is that they are quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things, first you want inexpensive stuff and second you want a heavy product means durable.
Both objectives are hard to achieve at the same time but still we try.

I only suggest here about kitchen stuff.

If you want to make kitchen cabinets,shelf, pantry cabinets then you may go for particle board.
Buy particle board and use it as your core material for creating cabinets. Particle board is much inexpensive and durable. After that you may hire a carpenter to make all cabinets.

Comment: Hiring a carpenter probably won't fall under the "inexpensive" category